# Java: Problems with Switch case

Tags: java

So I have a simple implementation of a Queue and I've been trying to make a switch case statement for it. Now it works quite alright. My issue is that it will ask if you want to continue, but even if you press "n" for "No" It will still continue.

Another thing is that I am unable to fill the array with random numbers at case3.

Code:
The implementation:

```
class Que{

    private int size;
    private int front = -1;
    private int rear = -1;
    private Integer[] queArr;

    public Que(int size) {
        this.size = size;
        queArr = new Integer[size];
    }
    public void insert(int item) {
        if(rear == size-1) {
            System.out.println("queue is overflowing");
        }
        else if(front==-1) {
            rear++;
            queArr[rear] = item;
            front = rear;
        }
        else {
            rear++;
            queArr[rear] = item;
        }
    }
    public void delete() {
        if(front == -1) {
            System.out.println("queue is underflow");
        }
        else if(front==rear) {
            System.out.println("removing "+queArr[front]);
            queArr[front] = null;
            front--;
            rear--;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("removing "+queArr[front]);

            queArr[front] = null;

            for(int i=front+1;i<=rear;i++) {
                queArr[i-1]=queArr[i];
            }
            rear--;
        }

    }
    public void display() {
        if(front==-1)
            System.out.println("queue is empty");
        else
        {
            System.out.println("queue is:");
            for(int i=front;i<=rear;i++) {
                System.out.print(queArr[i]+"\t");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Test:

```
import java.util.Random;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestQueue {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Hi user!");

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("please enter size of queue array");

    int size = scan.nextInt();

    Que que = new Que(size);

    char ch;

    do{

        System.out.println("\nQueue operations \n");

        System.out.println("1. insert");

        System.out.println("2. delete");

        System.out.println("3. random");

        int choice = scan.nextInt();

        switch(choice)

        {

            case 1: System.out.println("enter integer element to insert");

                que.insert(scan.nextInt());

                break;

            case 2:que.delete();

                break;

            case 3:  Random rand = new Random();

                rand.nextInt(size);

                break;

        }

        que.display();

        System.out.println("\nDo you want to continue (Type y or n) \n");

        ch = scan.next().charAt(0);

    }

    while(ch!='N' || ch!='n');

}

}
```

I also need some pointers on how to read out and display all prime numbers from the array. But that may be a topic for a different discussion.

I am thinking that I am screwing up with the while statement at the end of the Test.

Comment: consider using junit/ngunit for tests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
while(ch!='N' || ch!='n');
```

is always true (for any value of `ch`).

you need

```
 while(!(ch=='N' || ch=='n'));
```

Comment: ... or `while (ch!='N' && ch!='n')`

Comment: ahh now it works. Thanks!  Now, anyone ideas about the queue not being filled during case3? I was thinking that I mignt need to point it to the array differently.

Comment: @Sipko change `rand.nextInt(size);` to `que.insert(rand.nextInt(size));`